# Через время приложение WPF застывает и появляется кнопка 'Продолжить'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Я запускаю приложение WPF через Visual Studio 2022, вместе с запуском в бекграунде начинает проигрываться фон (mp4), который имеет бесконечный цикл

```
private void videoPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("playback");
        BackgroundVideo.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        BackgroundVideo.Play();
    }
```

Проходит пару секунд (~10) и приложение застывает без возможности его закрытия и передвижения. Я появляется кнопка 'Продолжить' как на скриншоте. Что делать? Как мне сделать, чтобы приложение работало до того момента, пока я сам его не закрою?

```
<MediaElement x:Name="BackgroundVideo" Source="Assets/GradientBackground.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Play" IsMuted="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" MediaEnded="videoPlayer_MediaEnded"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас приложение встало на паузу, то там произошла ошибка, студия должна была подсветить проблемное место и выдать ошибку. Если нет, читайте окно вывода, отлавливайте ошибку.

Comment: Не используйте `Console.WriteLine`, для вывода в отладочную еонсоль студии используйте `Debug.WriteLine`